# xrdp no screens found single GPU (nvidia)

Tags: linux, gnome, xrdp

I have issue to get work xrdp on my rocky linux 9, I tryed averythink but I can not pass this error message. On system runing GNOME Shell 40.10

with sesman parameter set to /usr/libexec/Xorg:

```
[    63.729] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    63.730] (++) Log file: ".xorgxrdp.10.log", Time: Thu Mar 16 09:29:14 2023
[    63.730] (++) Using config file: "/usr/libexec/Xorg"
[    63.730] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    63.730] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    63.730] Parse error on line 1 of section OutputClass in file /usr/libexec/Xorg
    "ELF" is not a valid keyword in this section.
[    63.730] (EE) Problem parsing the config file
[    63.730] (EE) Error parsing the config file
[    63.730] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    63.730] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    63.730] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
```

with sesman parameter set to Xorg:

```
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5676]: [INFO ] Session started successfully for user stepan.kukla on display 10
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5704]: [INFO ] Starting the xrdp channel server for display 10
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5678]: [INFO ] Starting the default window manager on display 10: /usr/libexec/xrdp/startwm-bash.sh
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5676]: [INFO ] Session in progress on display 10, waiting until the window manager (pid 5678) exits to end the session
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5679]: (EE)
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5679]: Fatal server error:
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5679]: (EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
Mar 16 10:47:58 vfxrocky-test xrdp-sesman[5679]: (EE)
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: this `Parse error on line 1 of section OutputClass in file /usr/libexec/Xorg "ELF" is not a valid keyword in this section.` seems to point to the exact line of the exact file that causes the error - what is the content of that file

Comment: That file is binary Xorg file /usr/libexec/Xorg its part of sesman conf.

```
[Xorg]
param=/usr/libexec/Xorg

```

Comment: that's odd, it says that's a config file in the messages ... anyway, seems there's a config files *somewhere* with a bad item in it

Comment: when I swtich to param=Xorg it say parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)